# how to fix InnoDB corrupted data structure?

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb

I removed mysql and installed mariadb, I guess removing mysql broke InnoDB (I'm new to this).

```
InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
```

Full Log:

```
    -- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has begun starting up.
Jan 16 18:25:55 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:55 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (mysqld 10.5.8-MariaDB) starting as process 6137 ...
Jan 16 18:25:55 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:55 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 16384 (request: 32183)
Jan 16 18:25:55 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Jan 16 18:25:55 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
Jan 16 18:25:55 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
Jan 16 18:25:55 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
Jan 16 18:25:55 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
Jan 16 18:25:55 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:55 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
Jan 16 18:25:55 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
Jan 16 18:25:55 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Jan 16 18:25:55 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed>
Jan 16 18:25:55 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:55 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Invalid flags 0x4800 in ./ibdata1
Jan 16 18:25:55 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:55 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
Jan 16 18:25:55 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Jan 16 18:25:56 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:56 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Jan 16 18:25:56 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:56 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Jan 16 18:25:56 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:56 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Jan 16 18:25:56 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:56 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be n>
Jan 16 18:25:56 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:56 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
Jan 16 18:25:56 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC mariadbd[6137]: 2021-01-16 18:25:56 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Jan 16 18:25:56 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 16 18:25:56 CentOSVPS1.DylanMediaPC systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
```

Edit1: According to the post below, the InnoDB implementation which used to be known as the "plugin" is included with mysql, and mariadb I'm presuming. So should I just reinstall mariadb to fix innodb?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-installation.html

> When you use the InnoDB storage engine 1.1 and above, with MySQL 5.5 and above, you do not need to do anything special to install: everything comes configured as part of the MySQL source and binary distributions.

Edit2: I used `yum history undo` on the install of mariadb, the removal of mysql and the install of mysql. Then installed mariadb. This didn't fix the problem but did clean up some unused mysql dependencies.

Edit3: The following commands from the post below solved my problem:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*
sudo mysql_install_db -u mysql
```

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/275885/innodb-failing-to-start-mysql-not-loading-plugins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: InnoDB: Invalid flags 0x4800 in ./ibdata1 when installing MariaDB on macOS Ventura via Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74305462/error-innodb-invalid-flags-0x4800-in-ibdata1-when-installing-mariadb-on-maco)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit3: The following commands from the post below solved my problem:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*
sudo mysql_install_db -u mysql
```

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/275885/innodb-failing-to-start-mysql-not-loading-plugins

Comment: But this will remove all data right?

Comment: worked, but need to restart before setting the password

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after removing mysql and installing mariadb. I had to remove all mysql files before being able to start mariadb:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mysql-files /var/lib/mysql-keyring
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*
```