# ERROR: InnoDB: Invalid flags 0x4800 in ./ibdata1 when installing MariaDB on macOS Ventura via Homebrew

Tags: mariadb, homebrew

I'm trying to install MariaDB (Ver 10.8.3-MariaDB for osx10.18 on arm64) via Homebrew (3.6.8) on macOS Ventura (13.0, Apple M1 Max) with the following steps:

1. `brew install mariadb`

   Summary looks fine:

   ```
   ==> Summary
     /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb/10.8.3_1: 917 files, 174.8MB
   ```

   But the following warning attracts my attention:

   ```
   Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
   You can try again using:
      brew postinstall mariadb
   ```
2. Then when I run `mysql` I get the error:

   ```
   ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
   ```
3. Running `mysqld` lists the following lines:

   ```
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [Note] mysqld (server 10.8.3-MariaDB) starting as process 94524 ...
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Invalid flags 0x4800 in ./ibdata1
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown variable 'mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1'
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [ERROR] Aborting
   ```

   **But unfortunately I have no clue how to solve the first listed error and I can't find any information about it:**

   ```
   2022-11-03 16:01:12 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Invalid flags 0x4800 in ./ibdata1
   ```
4. On advice I've deleted `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql` and reinstalled MariaDB, unfortunately with the same behavior afterwards. The new mysql direction contains:

   ```
   this-mac.local.err
   aria_log_control
   ib_logfile0
   aria_log.00000001
   ib_buffer_pool
   ibdata1
   ```

   The […].local.err now contains:

   ```
   221104 00:08:48 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [Note] /opt/homebrew/opt/mariadb/bin/mariadbd (server 10.8.3-MariaDB) starting as process 12788 ...
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 36426; transaction id 4
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [ERROR] /opt/homebrew/opt/mariadb/bin/mariadbd: unknown variable 'mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1'
   2022-11-04  0:08:48 0 [ERROR] Aborting
   221104 00:08:48 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/MacBook-Pro-von-Malte.local.pid ended
   ```

I'm thankful for any hint and I'd like to give any additional information, if needed.

Comment: Where did the database files came from? From previous installation?

Comment: @slaakso no, it's a clean installation on a new machine.

Comment: The [next versions of MariaDB](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/dc6a0171110741d633cef7877013d8e29d5e6def) will have a more explicit message: `InnoDB: MySQL-8.0 tablespace in ./ibdata1
InnoDB: Restart in MySQL for migration/recovery.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Invalid flags 0x4800 in ./ibdata1" is an indication that the datadir was installed with MySQL-8.0.

MariaDB cannot start on a MySQL-8.0 datadir.

Also "mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1" is a MySQL only system variable.

To install MariaDB you'll need to remove the MySQL datadir and configuration files first. (And backup any data there if its important).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Can you point me to the location of the MySQL-8.0 datadir? Do you mean `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql`? If so: I uninstalled MariaDB (brew uninstall mariadb), removed the mentioned mysql directory and tried to reinstall MariaDB (brew install mariadb) leading to the same behavior.

Comment: Yes - `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/` would seem to be the datadir from the logs. I can't explain how it survived your deletion. Can you list the contents of that directory in your question.

Comment: Just added them, the error logs have changed. Maybe a step forward? Still tricky to understand for me.

Comment: Look at the my.cnf files and remove `mysqlx-bind-address` out of the file. Missing `mysql.plugin` is odd, but not fatal. Can be corrected probably with `mariadb-upgrade --force`.

Comment: That worked, after removing `mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1` and a restart I can connect to mysql  Thanks a lot!